# How to change labels text in Swift 4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to change the text of my label called score with the contents of the currentScore but I keep getting an error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

I also get this error in the console:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Anyone ever encountered this? I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
@IBOutlet weak var score: UILabel!
var currentScore = 0    
let text = "You scored a \(currentScore) out of 3"
score.text = text
```

Comment: remove the previous iboutlet reference and again create iboutlet reference. hope solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Connect your `IBOutlet` to the label.
Everything else seems to be correct.